# requirejs - d3.sankey is not a function

Tags: javascript, d3.js, requirejs

I'm trying to create a basic sankey diagram using d3 libraries loaded from requirejs. In the past I've used the core d3 library and rendered everything fine, however in trying to load d3-sankey in this instance it doesn't seem to be registering. I've also tinkered around with the shim but I can't seem to figure out where the issue is specifically. Every time I try to load the attached code I get the error 'Uncaught TypeError: d3.sankey is not a function'.

I'm assuming the issue is the sequencing of libraries being loaded, but again I'm not sure how to resolve this. Can anyone help?

Codepen - https://codepen.io/quirkules/pen/wYoXxQ

```
// define URLs
require.config({
  paths: {
    cloudflare: 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs'
  },
  map: {
    '*': {
      'd3': 'cloudflare/d3/4.8.0/d3',
      'd3-timer': 'cloudflare/d3-timer/1.0.5/d3-timer',
      'd3-array': 'cloudflare/d3-array/1.2.2/d3-array',
      'd3-collection': 'cloudflare/d3-collection/1.0.5/d3-collection',
      'd3-interpolate': 'cloudflare/d3-interpolate/1.3.0/d3-interpolate',
      'd3-color': 'cloudflare/d3-color/1.2.1/d3-color',
      'd3-shape': 'cloudflare/d3-shape/1.2.0/d3-shape',
      'd3-path': 'cloudflare/d3-path/1.0.5/d3-path',
      'd3-sankey': 'cloudflare/d3-sankey/0.7.1/d3-sankey'
    }
  },
  shim : {
    d3 : {
      exports : 'd3'
    },
    'd3-sankey' : {
      deps: ['d3']
    }
  }
});

// load d3
require(['d3', 'd3-timer', 'd3-array', 'd3-collection', 'd3-interpolate', 'd3-color', 'd3-shape', 'd3-sankey'], function(d3) {
  //****** CREATE DIVS ******//

  // Add the divs to the DOM
  $(document.body)
    .append('<div id="header"></div>')
    .append('<div id="chart"></div>')
    .append('<div id="footer"></div>');
  //add text to the divs
  document.getElementById("header").innerHTML = '<b>Title</b>';

  // set the dimensions and margins of the graph
  var margin = { top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 40, left: 50 },
    width = d3.select('#chart').node().getBoundingClientRect().width - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = d3.select('#chart').node().getBoundingClientRect().height - margin.top - margin.bottom;

  //
  var svg = d3.select("#chart")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom);
  var g = svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

  var graph = d3.sankey()
    .nodeWidth(15)
    .nodePadding(10)
    .size([width, height]);

  var path = graph.link();

  var freqCounter = 1;

  //****** END CREATE CHART ******//
});
```

Comment: You are requiring `d3-sankey` but trying to create your graph wth `d3.sankey`.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by that @ksav?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why use require?

If I load the following 2 scripts it fails at the line `var path = graph.link();`, so `d3.sankey` is known and a function.

Undo all use of `require` and add

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.8.0/d3.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3-sankey/0.7.1/d3-sankey.min.js"></script>
```

`d3.js` already contains most of the other modules, it does not contain `d3-sankey`. For some reason `d3.js` does not register the individual modules it contains with `require()`, that's why require tries to load the modules `d3-array`, `d3-collection`, `d3-shape`, `d3-path`

Maybe you have a version problem, how do you know which version of the individual modules belong to d3.v4.8.0.

**Edit**

If I load `d3-sankey` after the other modules, the error disappears but if it works later on I don't know. (There are no links because there is no data processed by sankey.

```
require(['d3-selection', 'd3-timer', 'd3-array', 'd3-collection', 'd3-interpolate', 'd3-color', 'd3-shape'], function(d3) {
require(['d3-sankey'], function(dsankey) {
  //****** CREATE DIVS ******//
  // .....
  var graph = dsankey.sankey()
    .nodeWidth(15)
    .nodePadding(10)
    .size([width, height]);
  //****** END CREATE CHART ******//
});
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately I need to use require as I'm building this d3 viz using the KNIME analytics program, which only gives me access to the document body (along with a few preset libraries like jquery).

As for the versions, they all line up with the example I was following here https://bl.ocks.org/micahstubbs/ae0946f9efe18fc4f67460e7387abc0b. I stripped the code down as I wanted to make sure the sankey library was at least loaded before going further.

Comment: @Quirk the link does not use `require`. One way to solve it is to not load d3.4.8.0 and load all individual modules with require, like `d3-selection`

Comment: Right. I was trying to map this non-require example to the constraints I'm currently working under, which demands the use of requirejs to load all of my libraries. I'll try removing the 'd3' core library and loading each module individually.

Comment: Unfortunately it looks like I still get the same error when just using d3-selection https://codepen.io/quirkules/pen/YRPKNa

Comment: @Quirk: I managed to get rid of the error, see edit, also the height of your svg ==0 because the div#chart has no height

Comment: Thanks. I'll keep working with this nested solution and hopefully it holds up.

Comment: The order you declare the libraries from your index.html page is very important! In my case my sankey function does NOT work if it is declared before d3.js is declared.  So when I am declaring the libraries, 1st (top row) d3.js, and later (row BELOW) sankey.js.